# How to create three dimensional array with QHash?

Tags: qt, qhash

I want to create QHash with three arguments:

```
QHash <int, QString, float> myhash;
```

I know that I have to use nested QHash, so I did:

```
QHash <int, QHash<QString, float> > myhash;
```

But I could not figure out how I can insert values to myhash. 
I tried to create another Qhash  and insert this into my myhash, but I does not make any sence, since I have exactly 1 pair data for one key. 
What I want basically is :

```
0, "string1", 1.5
1, "string2", 1.2 etc.
```

How I can create efficiently (in terms of lookup time (the reason I am using QHash)) the above arrays. And how to insert values afterwards.

Thanks forward.

Comment: That's two-dimensional in your question, third value is the value in the cell of two dikensional table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `QHash <int, QHash<QString, float> > myhash;`, you can simply do this to set values:

```
myhash[42]["fortytwo"] = 42.42;
```

You can use the same syntax to access elements, but note that when accessed with non-const [`operator[]`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qhash.html#operator-5b-5d), these entries will actually be *created* in the hash. So it's often better to use [`value()` method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qhash.html#value):

```
if (myhash.value(43).value("fortytwo") >= 42) { /*...*/ }
```

Note that for `QHash` and `QMap`, accessing key which is not in the map is ok, [default constructed](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/containers.html#default-constructed-value) value is returned in that case. Above for first it means and empty hash, and for second, value `0.0f`.

---

To compare this to the method of using `QPair` from the other answer, this has the particular advantage that you can access elements by "rows" easily, if it matters for your use case (just make sure you have the nested hashes in the right order). Also, with this method, you could use different container for different dimensions, like if you need one dimension to be sorted use `QMap` (which is sorted by key) for that, and `QHash` (which is more efficient) for the dimension which doesn't need sorting. Additionally, you can have any number of dimensions easily, just add more nested containers.

On the other hand, if the key is logically a pair of values which are never separated, and data is not *really* (from programming perspective) organized as a two-dimensional table, then using `QPair` for key is probably better.

---

Unrelated to the question: to improve efficiency, in Qt 5 and C++11 [you could use `QStringLiteral("fortytwo")`](http://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html) to have the `QString` created already at compile time.

Comment: Big thanks for the detail answer. Now I can properly choose what is good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a QPair as your key:

```
QHash<QPair<int,QString>,float> myhash;
```

Insert values:

```
myhash.insert(QPair<int,QString>(1,"string1"),12.);
```

or

```
QPair<int,QString> p(1,"string1");

myhash[p] = 12.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can you please also show me how to insert values into myhash?

Comment: @user3185491: I've added insert examples.